# Which formula to use to calculate the main vibratory frequencies of a wooden joist floor? (8 Hz?)

Tags: materials, beam, wood

When a wooden floor joist is a little undersized, there is a vibration phenomenon when walking on the floor.

In some forums, I've often seen a frequency of 8 Hz mentioned when walking on the floor, and this seems to be true.

**Question: which physics formulas to use to compute the main vibration frequencies of a floor?** (given the length of joists, size of joists, distance between joists). If not possible directly with a formula, a simulated solution with a software is welcome.

Example:

[image]

Comment: You can research natural frequency of a simply supported beam.  Depending on how detailed you need to get and your capabilities, you might dig into the calculus.  You can think of it as a mass on a spring.  You need to figure how much the wood deforms as a function of force; this makes up the spring.  The force accelerates the mass that is the wood to bounce back, and that takes time, from which the frequency manifests.  The calculus can then break the wood into many masses on many springs with dependencies of the position along the length...